# Auto-close NERDTree when opening file in new tab

Tags: vim, nerdtree

When opening a file in a new tab in vim through NERDTree, I want the NERDTree window to be closed on the previous tab. The reason being, the tab title displays `NERDTree` in the previous tab. I want the default behavior, ie, the name of the file to be displayed rather than the word `NERDTree`. If I switch back to the previous tab and close the NERDTree window, the default behavior is noticed. What configuration settings do I need to add to auto-close `NERDTree` in my previous tab?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried setting:

`let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=1`

This worked for me.